# How to extract value from the JSON variant in snowflake?

Tags: json, snowflake-stage

I am copying data from S3 to snowflake as JSON variant in snowflake stage and not sure how can I extract the value from the string and load to another table.

Steps taken:

/* created json format */
create or replace  file format jsonformat
type='JSON'
strip_outer_array=true;

/*created table to store JSON variant */
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE  xyz.abc.CAN_IB_SCHEDULING_test (
JSON_DATA VARIANT
);

/*Copied the JSON data from snowflake stage to above created table */
COPY INTO CAN_IB_SCHEDULING_test
FROM @xyz.abc.CAN_IB_SCHEDULING_STG
FILE_FORMAT = (format_name = jsonformat);

select JSON_DATA
from  CAN_IB_SCHEDULING_test;

Example of the JSON variant

{"Appointment Date": "{"columnId":8275473196863364,"value":"2023-06-07","objectValue":{"objectType":"DATE","value":"2023-06-07"},"format":",,,,,,,,,12,,,,,,,"}",
"Appointment ID": "{"columnId":8331000681549700,"value":"MSKW000001","objectValue":"MSKW000001","displayValue":"MSKW000001","format":",,,,,,,,,12,,,,,,,"}",
"Appointment Insert Date": "{"columnId":3771873569492868,"value":"2023-06-02T18:08:56Z","objectValue":{"objectType":"DATETIME","value":"2023-06-02T18:08:56Z"},"format":",,,,,,,,,22,,,,,,,"}",
"Appointment Remark": "{"columnId":2699982876397444,"value":"Carrier Requested","objectValue":"Carrier Requested","displayValue":"Carrier Requested","format":",,,,,,,,,22,,,,,,,"}"

When I select the value  for a specific column it returns null.

*SELECT JSON_DATA:"Appointment Date".value FROM JSON_table;*

Expected ouput:

**Appointment Date   Appointment ID      Appointment Remark
2023-06-07         DFSW000001          Carrier Requested**

Answer (score 0):

so for extract the values from the JSON variant in Snowflake , you can use Snowflake's JSON parsing functions
like this :
***sql***

```
    SELECT
      JSON_DATA:"Appointment Date":value::string AS "Appointment Date",
      JSON_DATA:"Appointment ID":value::string AS "Appointment ID",
      JSON_DATA:"Appointment Remark":value::string AS "Appointment Remark"
    FROM CAN_IB_SCHEDULING_test;
```

Comment: I found what solution what i was looking for parsing the JSON helps.   PARSE_JSON(PARSE_JSON($1):"Appointment ID"):value::string AS "Appointment ID",